# Adding functions to a loaded node.js module

Tags: node.js

about 2 years ago, I wrote a node.js module that loads an existing module ([jsts](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts)) and adds some functions to it. Here is a minimal example:

```
global.jsts = require("jsts");
global.jsts.algorithm.test = function() {console.log("hi")}
global.jsts.algorithm.test();
```

I ran it in node (v0.10.18) and it printed

```
hi
```

Now, I run the same code in nodejs (v4.2.6) and it prints:

```
TypeError: global.jsts.algorithm.test is not a function
```

Is there a way to make it work with the current version of nodejs?

---

EDIT: I also did:

```
global.jsts.algorithm.x = 1
console.log(global.jsts.algorithm)
```

and here is the output:

```
{ Centroid: 
   { [Function: ge]
     area2: [Function],
     centroid3: [Function],
     getCentroid: [Function] },
  CGAlgorithms: 
   { [Function: he]
     orientationIndex: [Function],
     signedArea: [Function],
     distanceLineLine: [Function],
     isPointInRing: [Function],
     computeLength: [Function],
     isCCW: [Function],
     locatePointInRing: [Function],
     distancePointLinePerpendicular: [Function],
     computeOrientation: [Function],
     distancePointLine: [Function],
     isOnLine: [Function],
     CLOCKWISE: -1,
     RIGHT: -1,
     COUNTERCLOCKWISE: 1,
     LEFT: 1,
     COLLINEAR: 0,
     STRAIGHT: 0 },
  ConvexHull: 
   { [Function: me]
     extractCoordinates: [Function],
     RadialComparator: { [Function: ye] polarCompare: [Function] } },
  InteriorPointArea: 
   { [Function: oi]
     centre: [Function],
     avg: [Function],
     SafeBisectorFinder: { [Function: ai] getBisectorY: [Function] } },
  InteriorPointLine: [Function: ui],
  InteriorPointPoint: [Function: li],
  RobustLineIntersector: { [Function: ae] nearestEndpoint: [Function] },
  MCPointInRing: { [Function: Ii] MCSelecter: [Function: Ni] },
  MinimumBoundingCircle: 
   { [Function: wi]
     pointWitMinAngleWithX: [Function],
     lowestPoint: [Function],
     pointWithMinAngleWithSegment: [Function] },
  MinimumDiameter: 
   { [Function: Li]
     nextIndex: [Function],
     computeC: [Function],
     getMinimumDiameter: [Function],
     getMinimumRectangle: [Function],
     computeSegmentForLine: [Function] } }
```

Comment: Check that `global.jsts.algorithm` is `object`. If it is `number` or `boolean` then function can be assigned but raise error on call.

Comment: @AikonMogwai  added a line "console.log(typeof(global.jsts.algorithm))" and it prints "object".

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi can you show some output of console.log(global.jsts.algorithm)

Comment: `Object.isExtensible(global.jsts.algorithm)` return `false`, so `.test =` didn't change it.

Comment: @AikonMogwai you are right: in the old version it returns "true" and in the new version it returns "false". So what can I do to make my code work with the new version?

Comment: You can create copy of object by `global.jsts.algorithm = Object.assign({}, global.jsts.algorithm);`

Comment: @AikonMogwai This works great. Thanks!